# How to populate the values from another component into the redux form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

Is there a way to load the values default into the redux-form. I have the values like topicName and topicDescription from the main component. When I click and route to the redux-form for edit, I want these values to loaded already for edit and I should just append the data, on onSubmit the new values should be loaded into the form. Thank you

```
 class EditRow extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props)

            this.state={
                topicName:this.props.location.state.topicName,
                topicDescription:this.props.location.state.avgGrade
            }
            this.onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this)
        }

        renderTextField(field){
            return(
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>{field.label}</label>
                    <input
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder={field.placeholder}
                        {...field.input}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
        onSubmit(values){
            this.props.editRow(values, () => {
                this.props.history.push({pathname:'/Topics/'+ this.props.match.params.editId +'/'+ this.props.match.params.categoryId+'/id/'+this.props.match.params.userName,
                    state:{description:this.props.location.state.description,dateTime:this.props.location.state.dateTime,topicName:this.props.location.state.topicName}} );
            },this.props.match.params.objectId);
        }
        render(){

            const {handleSubmit}=this.props;

            const editrow={
                backgroundColor: "white",
                padding: "50px",
                boxShadow: '0 0 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
                minWidth: '100px',
                maxWidth: '95%',
                margin: "150px auto 50px auto"
            }
            return(
                <form style={editrow} onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                    <Field
                        label={"Topic Name"}
                        placeholder={"Enter the Name"}
                        name="name"
                        component={this.renderTextField}
                    />
                    <Field
                        label={"Average Grade"}
                        placeholder={"Enter the Average grade"}
                        name="avgGrade"
                        component={this.renderTextField}
                    />
                    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-right">Edit</button>
                </form>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the docs? Not 100% sure about this, but I think you can use initial value https://redux-form.com/7.0.2/examples/initializefromstate/

Comment: Thanks for the documentation

Comment: Yep. You just need to pass down `initialValues` prop down to your decorated redux form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `initialValues` prop down to your form, as it's described in the [documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.0.2/examples/initializefromstate/):

```
// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState' // a unique identifier for this form
})(InitializeFromStateForm)

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: {
      topicName: state.location.state.topicName,
      topicDescription: state.location.state.avgGrade
    }
  })
)(InitializeFromStateForm)

export default InitializeFromStateForm
```

Comment: I already have this in my export function, so how could you add initializeFrom in this export default reduxForm({form:'EditRow'})(connect (null,{editRow})(EditRow))

Comment: You should pass down `initialValues` to your decorated reduxForm `form`, as follows:  `const form = reduxForm({ form:'EditRow' })(EditRow); export default  connect((state, props) =>({ initialValues: { topicName: state.location.state.topicName,topicDescription: state.location.state.avgGrade
    } }))(form)`

Comment: The way you did it above, the reduxForm won't have access to `InitialValues`.

Answer (score 2):

After adding this like initialized the states from the syntax below. I got the desired output.

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
         return { initialValues: {name:ownProps.location.state.topicName, Description:ownProps.location.state.Description}}
    };

    EditRow  = reduxForm({
        validate,
        form: 'EditForm',
        enableReinitialize: true,
    })(EditRow );

    EditRow  = connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        {
         editRow
        },
    )(EditRow );

    export default withRouter(EditRow );
```